# Python Simple Vignere Decrypt Function

Tags: python, string, encryption

Alright, I have homework. It's late and my brain is not functioning very well.
I have the following functions that are cluttering my final result (but I have to use them):

```
def letterToIndex(char):
    az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    idx = az.find(char)
    if idx < 0:
        print ("err: not in here ", char)
    return idx

def indexToLetter(idx):
    az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    if idx > 25:
        print ("err: ", idx, " too large")
        letter = ''
    elif idx < 0:
        print "err: ", idx , "should not be this"
    else:
    return letter
```

Also, this one, which apparently is the one causing the issue (I am still not clear on how to reverse that mode 26):

```
def vigneIndex(keylet, plainlet):
    keyIdx = letterToIndex(keylet)
    plainIdx = letterToIndex(plainlet)
    newIdx = (plainIdx + keyIdx) % 26
    return indexToLetter(newIdx)
```

And finally these are my encryptor / decryptor:

```
def encryptVigne(key,string):
    cipher = ''
    keyLen = len(key)
    for i in range(len(string)):
        char = string[i]
        if char == ' ':
            cipher = cipher + char
        else:
            cipher = cipher + vigneIndex(key[i%keyLen], char)
    return cipher
```

The encryptor works.

```
nkey = 'abc'
print nkey
print encryptVigne(nkey, 'testing')
cip = encryptVigne(nkey, 'testing')

def undoVigne(key,cipher):
    string = ''
    keyLen = len(key)
    for i in range(len(cipher)):
        char = cipher[i]
        if char == ' ':
            string = string + char
        else:
            string = string + vigneIndex(key[i%keyLen], char)
    return string
```

But the decryption does not decrypt it. I've been told that it is as easy as reversing the process, but clearly I am missing something in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but from the flying view it looks like your function `indexToLetter` is not working properly. Try to change it by this one:

```
def indexToLetter(idx):
    az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    if idx > 25:
        print("err: ", idx, " too large")
        return ''
    elif idx < 0:
        print("err: ", idx , "should not be this")
        return ''
    else:
        return az[idx]
```

But you should raise an exception instead of printing messages to the output stream if `idx` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but it is not. I have the feeling I have to invert the mode % 26 or something like that but im falling asleep now

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually code to decrypt it?

For example, when reversing the process (decrypting), in the function: `encryptVigne`, shouldn't you be taking:

```
newIdx = (plainIdx - keyIdx) % 26
```

to reverse what you did when encrypting:

```
newIdx = (plainIdx + keyIdx) % 26
```